# Debug Assertion Failed - OpenCv lkdemo in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to run this sample program [lkdemo.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp) when I tried to execute in visual studio 2015 got "Debug assertion failed"as

[image: Assertion]

I tried with debugging but Can't able to locate the error . 
Can anyone help me to solve this .. 
Thanks in advance .